# Screen sharing Integration in HTML5 LOB?

Tags: asp.net, html, remote-debugging, screensharing

I’m just wondering if anyone knows of any screen sharing packages out there that will integrate into a HTML5 based line of business app. The use case is if a user calls in they can just click share screen with support and the support person in here will be able to see and take hold of their screen.

I know there is a lot of packages out there that do this but they all seem to require some type of plugin to run them.

Any advice is appreciated.